# Exclusive Access Per User

Tags: c#

I have chunk of code which I wanna make sure **same user** cannot access more than 1 time concurrently.

I know in C# the below code can only be executed by single user at a time,

```
        lock (privateObjectLock)
        {

        }
```

What I am looking is that user1,user2,...userN should be able to access the code region concurrently but user1 should not be able to execute concurrently.

Why I need this? Because if same user sending multiple requests at same time, consider,

```
        if (balanceAvailableOfAUser)
        {
            UserCanBuy();
            DeductAmount();
        }
```

From SQL Server side, we can use serializable isolation level (or optimistic concurrency) to avoid this but I am thinking whether something available in C# as well.

**Update 1:**

Based on David, I have some with this so far,

```
public class UserLocker
{
    static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, SemaphoreSlim> _semaphores = new();

    public static async Task<T> LockAsync<T>(int userId, Func<Task<T>> worker)
    {
        var semaphore = _semaphores.GetOrAdd(userId, new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await worker();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
            _semaphores.TryRemove(userId, out semaphore);
        }
    }
}
```

calling like,

```
        var response = await UserLocker.LockAsync(user.Id, async () =>
        {
            if (user.SomCondition)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("AddSomeError", "AddSomeError");
                return null;
            }                
            var response = SaveSomeThing();
            return response;
        });
        if (response == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(new ValidationProblemDetails(ModelState));
        }
        return Ok(response);
```

Comment: What kind of application is this (ASP.NET (if so, web forms, MVC), etc.)?

Comment: Maybe you can use a named lock by the user's ID, something like `lock(user.Id){...}`
Edit: found this https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233703-named-locks-using-monitor-in-net-implementation

Comment: @TeodorVladutu You can't lock on a value type.

Comment: @Flydog57 ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a dictionary of [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-6.0) objects and use the user ID as the key. For example:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<int, SemaphoreSlim> _semaphores = new();

public async Task DoStuffForUser(int userId)
{
    var semaphore = _semaphores.GetOrAdd(userId, x => new SemaphoreSlim(1));
    
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();

    Console.WriteLine($"Starting stuff for {userId}");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine($"Ending stuff for {userId}");

    semaphore.Release();
}
```

Now this code:

```
var tasks = new Task[]
{
    DoStuffForUser(1),
    DoStuffForUser(2),
    DoStuffForUser(1),
};

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Would give you this output, note how the calls for user 1 are never interleaved, it's always 1 starting and finishing before another starts:

```
Starting stuff for 1
Starting stuff for 2
Ending stuff for 1
Ending stuff for 2
Starting stuff for 1
Ending stuff for 1
```

Comment: How can we remove old or unused semaphores to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: 1000 semaphores are going to use less than 200kb of memory, do you really need to worry about that?

Comment: shouldn't _semaphores be static?

Comment: Does this work if I replace object with int https://gist.github.com/JimBobSquarePants/208ff72e0a93abca4043

Comment: I have updated the question with possible solution. If you can take a look, it will be great.